# How do I create a dynamic search filter in an HTML dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

So the scenario is this:
I have a range of cells in google sheets -> A1:A. It has Names.
I want to create an HTML form that pulls information from those cells and lists them in a dropdown.
It should allow searching and filtering in the dropdown.

I found this tutorial that helps me create a button and filter for data. I might have a way to get the data range from there, but I can't (don't know how) to make the resulted value (after search) become the value of the cell.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't get the value selected to become the field value (like click it and it becomes the value).

I imagine i can get the range in the script section and pass it to the filter function.

But one problem at a time.
I am really new at HTML, so any input would help !

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```js
// Listen on the 'click' event inside the myDropdown element:
document.querySelector("#myDropdown").addEventListener("click", e =>{
  // If the click was triggered by an <a> element:
  if (e.target.nodeName !== "A"){
    return;
  }
  // Set the value of the selected text to the input value:
  document.querySelector("#myInput").value = e.target.textContent;
  // Or, you can get the href value, minus the #
  // document.querySelector("#myInput").value = e.target.getAttribute("href").slice(1);
})
```

Check the comments on the ADDITIONAL CODE for more details.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// ADDITIONAL CODE >>
// Listen on the 'click' event inside the myDropdown element"
document.querySelector("#myDropdown").addEventListener("click", e =>{
  // If the click was triggered by an <a> element:
  if (e.target.nodeName !== "A"){
    return;
  }
  // Set the value of the selected text to the input value:
  document.querySelector("#myInput").value = e.target.textContent;
})
// << ADDITIONAL CODE

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know I might be asking a lot, but is there a way to have it not require click Drop-down, and just be a drop-down that you can search in it and it applies the filter ?

Comment: I think you can accomplish that by removing the Dropdown handler. Just display the search list by default. Wouldn't that work like you describe?